# Why am I getting a namespace error when I thought I already defined what needs to be defined?

Tags: c#

I am not sure why I am getting a namespace error when I a made sure to declare it.

At first I had the FieldCollectionClass declared as private and changed it to public and that didn't change it so what am I missing?

I have added my code without the suggestions of how to fix the issue. Basically edited my original question and added more of my original code to help with the problem.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace NewCode
 {
 class CommandLineArguments
  {


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    public class ComparisonLogic
    {
        #region 'Declarations'

        public int _noDifferenceFieldCount = 0;
        public int _recordsNotFoundCount = 0;
        private string _compareFieldsString = string.Empty;
        public FieldCollectionClass _Fields = new FieldCollectionClass();

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int Profile
        {
            get { return Profile; }
            set { Profile = value; }
        }

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int File1
        {
            get { return File1; }
            set { File1 = value; }
        }

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int File2
        {
            get { return File2; }
            set { File2 = value; }
        }

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int Delimiter
        {
            get { return Delimiter; }
            set { Delimiter = value; }
        }

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int CounterDifferencesFields
        {
            get { return _noDifferenceFieldCount; }
            set { _noDifferenceFieldCount = value; }

        }

        // Gets and Sets the values for the profile and the files accessed at the command line
        public int CounterRecordsNotFound
        {
            get { return _recordsNotFoundCount; }
            set { _recordsNotFoundCount = value; }
        }

        public FieldCollectionClass 
        {
            get { return _Fields; }
            set { _Fields = value; }
        }


        public int NumberOfFieldsToCompare
        {
            get
            {
                int recordNum = 0;
                if (this.File1 < this.File2)
                    recordNum = this.File1;
                else
                    recordNum = this.File2;

                return recordNum * this.CompareFields.Count;

            }
        }


        public System.Data.DataSet CompareResults
        {
            get { return _dsResult; }           

        }




        public FieldCollectionClass CompareFields
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.File1.GetCompareFields().Count < this.File2.GetCompareFields().Count)
                    return this.File1.GetCompareFields();
                else
                    return this.File2.GetCompareFields();

            }

        }
```

**Error:**
The namespace name 'FieldCollectionClass' could not be found

Comment: Do you have `using FieldCollectionClass` somewhere at the top of your file? If you do, you shouldn't. It looks like `FieldCollectionClass` is a class, not a namespace. You haven't shown where that class is defined though, so it's really just a guess.

Comment: @itsme86 No I don't these are my using statements: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
unless one of these is linked to that? I did copy some of this code from another file could that be a reason? The file I got this section of code from though doesn't have FieldCollectionClass as a namespace. I tried changing collectionofFields but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Rory What is the Namespace of the FieldCollectionClass? Add it as a using statement at the top of your file.

Comment: @Fraser the namespace is CompareFilesUtility.Classes I did what you said but for some reason it still doesn't like it.

Comment: @Rory What is the access modifier on the FieldCollectionClass?

Comment: I think we're going to have to see more of your code file. Maybe there's unbalanced curly braces or an incomplete statement?

Comment: @itsme86 I added the rest of my code without the suggestions.

Comment: @Fraser I added the rest of my code without the suggestions .

Comment: The code you pasted has you defining a class within a method. You can't do that.